# Can't manage cookies in custom 404 or 500 actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got custom 404 and 500 pages set up for my app via routing of '400' and '500'. There is a certain before filter that runs before them and also a couple of other actions. I've noticed that when before filter runs before those actions, it can delete cookies, but not if the action is 404 or 500 action. I've experimented and put cookie deleting code into the actions themselves, rather than in the filter, but the same thing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: What is it precisely you want to do with these cookies? It sounds like there's multiple things your asking to here. So it appears you have a `before_filter` just to clarify a `before_filter` doesn't <b>filter</b> out actions. A `before_filter` is a method that is ran <b>before</b> a particular action is rendered. From the sounds of it your saying your particular `before_filter` is deleting your cookies.

Comment: @David Yes, I am aware that before filters are there to be run before actions, not to filter them. A particular before filter has to delete cookies, and it works fine unless the action it runs before is a custom 404 or 500 action